# Forex rates for financial apps

Tags: javascript, php, finance, low-latency, forex

I need to show live Forex rates in web/mobile apps like in `iqoption.com` for example.

I've tried yahoo finance, but they don't update the rates as fast as I want.

Where I can get the data for this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

### Not as fast as I want?

There are few possible reasons
- a ( transport + processing ) latency + distribution-policy bound delay & synthetic "sub-sampling" ( sending less frequent updates than the quote-stream provider records )

- a market does not generate changes in price so "often" as you would like or expected to observe ( a shallow-liquidity market with not big crowd making contracts overthere as a trivial example )
- a market is closed at a particular time ( closed market or weekend )

### Online sources for a NTO data-stream <sub>( XTO streams are rather brutal )</sub>

You might like to test [something like this](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lmax-widget/website-widget-quote-inst-flex.html?a=LQlaT12daeSqEAFt) and process the server-side updates in your app.

Your app design shall expect harsh conditions to survive.

Typically
**several dozens updates per each milisecond** in prime time,
**spurious bursts** of updates, having a millisecond or two to process <sup>...get rid of</sup>  'em all
[image]

some protocols even expose your side to countless schemes following a reset in keeping pace in protocol handshaking ( smart & compliant error-handling is your main bread and butter issue for survival )

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------[mini-flash-crash 2014-01-06 15h14m [UTC+0000]]
15:43:17,812 <44 MarketDataIncrementalRefresh (8=FIX.4.29=97835=X34=4449=:::52=20140106-14:43:14.67756=/\/\/\/\/262=20140106-14:43:17.171268=13279=0269=0278=83655=EUR/USD270=1.3612215=EUR271=1500000346=2279=0269=0278=83455=EUR/USD270=1.3612115=EUR271=1000000346=1279=0269=0278=84255=EUR/USD270=1.3612615=EUR271=6500000346=1279=0269=0278=84455=EUR/USD270=1.3612515=EUR271=11000000346=2279=0269=0278=84055=EUR/USD270=1.3612415=EUR271=4000000346=1279=0269=0278=83855=EUR/USD270=1.3612315=EUR271=10500000346=2279=0269=0278=84655=EUR/USD270=1.3612715=EUR271=4100000346=1279=0269=1278=86755=EUR/USD270=1.3613815=EUR271=500000346=1279=0269=1278=86155=EUR/USD270=1.3613415=EUR271=7100000346=1279=0269=1278=86355=EUR/USD270=1.3613515=EUR271=6500000346=1279=0269=1278=86555=EUR/USD270=1.3613615=EUR271=6000000346=1279=0269=1278=86955=EUR/USD270=1.3613715=EUR271=3000000346=1279=0269=1278=85955=EUR/USD270=1.3613315=EUR271=3500000346=110=183)
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : NOT_FIX_MESSAGE - Not enough bytes in the message : 
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : NOT_FIX_MESSAGE - Not enough bytes in the message : 
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : NOT_FIX_MESSAGE - End of stream while reading fix-message
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : NOT_FIX_MESSAGE - End of stream while reading fix-message
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : INCORRECT_SECOND_TAG - Incorrect body length tag : 8=227
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : INCORRECT_SECOND_TAG - Incorrect body length tag : 8=227
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : INCORRECT_SECOND_TAG - Incorrect body length tag : 8=83255
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : INCORRECT_SECOND_TAG - Incorrect body length tag : 8=83255
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : INCORRECT_SECOND_TAG - Incorrect body length tag : 8=83455
15:43:17,812 WARNING: Received garbled message : INCORRECT_SECOND_TAG - Incorrect body length tag : 8=83455
15:43:17,812 <46 MarketDataIncrementalRefresh (8=FIX.4.29=29735=X34=4649=:::52=201401
15:43:17,812 WARNING: MsgSeqNum too high, expecting 45 but received 46 in MarketDataIncrementalRefresh
```